# Populate 2 dropdown lists using hibernate - one is null

Tags: hibernate

I have 2 drop down lists, each to be populated with data from different tables. I have created 2 different DAO classes and list methods, but the second list is coming as null.

public class GenderDAO {

```
private ArrayList<Gender> genders;
static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GenderDAO.class);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public ArrayList<Gender> listGenders() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        genders = (ArrayList<Gender>) session.createQuery("from Gender").list();
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        logger.debug("In the GenderDAO HibernateException");
        transaction.rollback();
    } finally {
        logger.debug("In the GenderDAO finally block");
        session.close();
    }
    return genders;
}
```

public class StateDAO {

```
private ArrayList<State> states;
static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(StateDAO.class);

@SuppressWarnings ("unchecked")
public ArrayList<State> listStates() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        states = (ArrayList<State>) session.createQuery("from State").list();
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        logger.debug("In the StateDAO HibernateException");
        transaction.rollback();
    } finally {
        logger.debug("In the StateDAO finally block");
        session.close();
    }
    return states;
}
```

}

I get the following error.

tag 'select', field 'list', name 'state': The requested list key 'states' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name}

If I add the following before executing the query in StateDAO, error goes away but the list is empty.

states = new ArrayList();

Code to call the DAO methods is as follows:

```
    GenderDAO genderDAO = new GenderDAO();
    genders = genderDAO.listGenders();

    StateDAO stateDAO = new StateDAO();
    states = stateDAO.listStates();
```

Can someone suggest what is missing?